# Error when login with Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook-login

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpANieebE2M, But I used CocoaPod to install FBSDK, not download framework and drag to my project.

I used **FBSDK Version: 4.10.1**

Here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'GiftsToMyFriends' do
    pod "FBSDKCoreKit"
    pod "FBSDKLoginKit"
    pod "FBSDKShareKit"
    pod "FBSDKMessengerShareKit"
end
```

Here is my LoginViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKMessengerShareKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil) {
            print("Not loged in..")
        } else {
            print("Loged in...")
        }

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

}

extension LoginViewController: FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

        if error == nil {
            print("login completed...")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goTo", sender: self)
        } else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Loged out...")
    }
}
```

But when I click to login button here:

[image]

It goes crash:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, `fbauth2` is missing from your info.plist file. You need to add this to your info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fbapi20130214</string>
  <string>fbapi20130410</string>
  <string>fbapi20130702</string>
  <string>fbapi20131010</string>
  <string>fbapi20131219</string>    
  <string>fbapi20140410</string>
  <string>fbapi20140116</string>
  <string>fbapi20150313</string>
  <string>fbapi20150629</string>
  <string>fbauth</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't mention any specific version in the cocoa pods and if you have just integrated cocoa pods than you have to include only as you have higher SDK version than 4.6.0

If you're using v4.6.0 or higher of the SDK, you only need to add:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

If you version is still lower than 4.6.0 you can check Ahmed's answer

Also please check the if you have set the facebook app id in the plist if you still get the error after adding the LSApplicationQueriesSchemas

More information regarding that can be found in [Getting Started : Facebook ios SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)
Check `5. Configure Xcode Project`

Comment: I used FBSDK Version: 4.10.1, and try as you said, but didn't work